# cannot open output file in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

[image: compiler continues to show the error message]

I tried re installing JDK 1.8 and qt itself, but the error is not removing and neither there is any output.I also tried through disabling anti virus, but all the efforts went in vain.Can anybody suggest me a good solution to this problem ?

Comment: When you create the project put a path that is in the documents folder

Comment: I uninstalled my antivirus and now it's working fine. 
But I guess I  obviusly need an antivirus and not sure how to adjust it with qt.